# bitcoin files mysteriously show up in trash

Tags: bitcoin-core

I'm usually pretty good at figuring things out, but this one has me stumped. Yesterday I saw 5 or so (don't remember exactly) bitcoin-qt(something).gz files in my trash that i had NOT sent there. It was late and I was tired so left it for the morning. This morning upon starting up, they were gone. I checked through most logs including apt, dmesg, changelog, etc. for clues, but found nothing.

My coins are still in the wallet now and it is encrypted. Should I worry?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Edit:
Maybe there was some update and the files were moved to the trash to be purged upon restart...? I find no evidence of an update yesterday. Maybe I missed something. Bitcoin-qt is in my sources.list. However, I find no such info in the changelog...